# in the activity stream of a gitlab project's home page, commits are associated with incorrect user

Tags: gitlab

has anyone seen this before?  if so, how did you go about fixing this?

in my git repo, commits by an user (J) are listed with another user (S) on the project's home page activities stream.  if i click on one of these commits, it takes me to the commit page.  Here, the author name is correct.  in mysql's event table, I definitely see the problem.  in example below, the event entry has different user_name than author

```
| 5047 | NULL        |      NULL | NULL  | ---
:before: 2ab9bd30a20529bdeeaab21e14767ab7cf1b117c
:after: 3a43bd7b00c099c2a15bbdd99282ac2c0ed4e231
:ref: refs/heads/master
:user_id: 68
:user_name: S******
:project_id: 163
:repository:
  :name: *************
  :url: ******************
  :description: ''
  :homepage:***************
:commits:
- :id: !binary |-
    MjY2YmNlZGI0MTM2MjYxNmQxZjExOTMyZDlkMjliMWQ5OWY1N2ZlZQ==
  :message: ! '**********'
  :timestamp: '2014-03-27T11:06:46-07:00'
  :url: http://*****************
  :author:
    :name: J******
    :email: j*******
- :id: !binary |-
    M2E0M2JkN2IwMGMwOTljMmExNWJiZGQ5OTI4MmFjMmMwZWQ0ZTIzMQ==
  :message: ! '*****'
  :timestamp: '2014-03-27T12:23:59-07:00'
  :url: **************
  :author:
    :name: J******
    :email: j**********
:total_commits_count: 2
 |        163 | 2014-03-27 19:27:53 | 2014-03-27 19:27:53 |      5 |        68 |
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this ? We have the same problem... Version 7.1.1

Comment: If you could link to a public repo on gitlab.com that reproduces that would help a lot. Also please open an issue at gitlab and link to it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found that the user who was supposed to be showing up had the SSH-key for the incorrect user in `.ssh/id_rsa.pub` which resulted in the wrong user being identified in the post receive hook in gitlab.  Fixing the key fixed the issue.

Comment: Though I am not able to correct the past entries.  Updating the database does not translate into changes in the Dashboard.

Comment: In order to get db changes to immediately show up, in config/environments/production.rb set `config.action_controller.perform_caching = false`